# Get certain parameter on a fetch request

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm developing a twitter-like app where users are able to make posts.
I want to make a div containing the Username posting, the post content, and the date.

Since the username is a ForeignKey, I had some errors until I was able to fetch the whole User table.

I only need to get the username field, which seems to be a dictionary inside and list, as I'll show below.

Below, you may find the codes:
**The Models**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class PostData(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True) # In case I want to add a delete feature in the future
    post_content = models.CharField(max_length=360)
    date_post_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    user_posting = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="userposting")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.post_content}"

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "post_content": self.post_content,
            "user_posting":serializers.serialize("json", User.objects.all()),
            "date_post_created": self.date_post_created
        }
```

**The views.py**

```
def all_posts(request):
    # Get posts.
    posts = PostData.objects.all()
    #Return in reverse chronological order
    posts = posts.order_by("-date_post_created").all()
    return JsonResponse([post.serialize() for post in posts], safe=False)
```

**The posts.js (which has the code to feed the html)**

```
function load_posts(){


    fetch('allposts')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(posts => {

        posts.forEach(element => {
            console.log(element.post_content);
            console.log(element.user_posting);
            console.log(element.date_post_created);
```

(...)

The current output:

> **from console.log(element.post_content);** teste teste teste

** from console.log(element.user_posting); **

> [ {"model": "network.user",  "pk": 1,
> "fields":     {"password":
> "pbkdf2_sha256$216000$C13hJOjD4ojv$AW5a0AFEisWO7IG0MkVNQ8k6+OnfN0CljEV8lnfEaKE=",
> "last_login": "2021-01-29T00:01:37.127Z",   "is_superuser": false,
> "username": "Igor",    "first_name": "",   "last_name": "",    "email":
> "igor@igor.pt",    "is_staff": false,      "is_active": true,
> "date_joined": "2021-01-25T17:02:11.514Z",     "groups": [],
> "user_permissions": []    } } ]

> **from console.log(element.date_post_created);** 2021-01-25T23:48:03.515Z

I want to extract the field **username** that in this case contains **Igor**.
I've tried:

```
console.log(element.user_posting[0]['fields']['username']);
```

When I try:

```
console.log(element.user_posting[0].fields.username);
```

Got an error:

```
( Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined at posts.js:26 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at posts.js:23
```

Comment: Since the data returned is an array of JSON Objects, you'd use `element.user_posting[0].fields.username`. You use [] to access array and dot notation (parentNode.childNode) to access objects.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Got an error :(
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
  at posts.js:26
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at posts.js:23

Comment: Could you try to do `let user = JSON.parse(element.user_posting[0]); console.log(user.fields.username);` I guess the content of the array is a string and not already parsed as an object, so using JSON.parse() would make it an object.

Comment: thanks, got as error:
" Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" ///
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at posts.js:26 >> let user = JSON.parse(element.user_posting[0]); ///
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at posts.js:23 >> posts.forEach(element => { ///

I've spend 3hours around this yesterday. I'll finish a report and I'll look again into this tonight. :( Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: Django provides session user when logged in and anonymous user when logged out. I think you are not handling this case - when logged out.

Answer (score 1):

> Could you try to do let user = JSON.parse(element.user_posting[0]);
> console.log(user.fields.username); I guess the content of the array is
> a string and not already parsed as an object, so using JSON.parse()
> would make it an object. – user1453870 11 hours ago

Hey man, your answer was almost right, we just had to move the [0] out of the parse. The way it worked was:

```
let user = JSON.parse(element.user_posting);

console.log(user[0].fields.username);
```

Thanks everyone for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

Django provides `session user` for default `User` model when logged in and `anonymous user` when logged out. I think you are not handling this case - when logged out. You can use `@login_required` decorator. So only loged in users can see your post.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    
@login_required
def all_posts(request):
    # Get posts.
    posts = PostData.objects.all()
    #Return in reverse chronological order
    posts = posts.order_by("-date_post_created").all()
    return JsonResponse([post.serialize() for post in posts], safe=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. In fact I have that decorator, I didn't paste it to avoid adding information that I believe it would not be needed. My daughter is going to sleep soon.
I think I will solve this "problem" another way. I will create another view just to query the author. Maybe it's excessive but I  think will be the easiest way to solve it :D